# preg_match to select outside string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

```
$newpair = '~I love~~you~ notes';

preg_match_all ('^\~(.*?)\~^' , $newpair, $np);

foreach($np[1] as $key ){
print_r($np[1]);
echo $key .'<br/>';
}

echo $np; //result: I love you
```

Above preg_match echo the string inside the `~`

Can you help create an expression to echo the outside text `notes`?

Comment: `$np` is an array, echo'ing it would not produce the result you're giving. You also don't need to escape `~`, it's not a metadata character.

Comment: edited the question. i've added a loop to echo the `$np`

Comment: Your question isn't clear. I understand that you want to catch the text inside ~ delimiters, but what *outside string* means exactly? If my string is `groin~I love~groin~you~ notes`, is the result `I love you` and `groin groin notes` as *outside string*?

Answer (score 1):

```
$outside = preg_replace('#~[^~]*~#', '', $newpair);
```

This would return a string that consists of everything outside the paired tildas.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the last `~` with a positive lookbehind, then continue capturing everything that's not a `~` until you reach the end of the string with `$`:

```
(?<=~)[^~]+$
```

Using it like this:

```
$newpair = '~I love~~you~ notes';
preg_match_all ('/(?<=~)[^~]+$/' , $newpair, $np);
var_dump( $np[0][0]);
```

[Prints](http://viper-7.com/97u9DL):

```
string(6) " notes"
```

Comment: `[^~]+$` would provide identical result (in this case). PS: not sure, but OP didn't mention the "outside" part will always be in the end of the string

Comment: Good point, I was considering the case where the input string has no `~`, and am not sure if that should match or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$subject = '~I love~~you~ notes';
$pattern = '/~\K[^~]++(?=~)/';

preg_match_all ($pattern, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);

$result = implode(' ', $matches[0]);

echo $result;
```

Note that for the pattern i make the choice to check if there's a `~` after the match with a lookahead `(?=...)`, but if this isn't a necessary condition you can remove it.

The `\K` is reset the start of the pattern.